# How do you "mark" a group of Python methods for later use? (Can these decorators be improved?)

Tags: python, decorator

I'd like to mark some methods (class methods in this case, but not necessarily) as related so I can use them together. I don't want to create a hardcoded list of the methods inside `all_fruit` because I don't want it to be missed when adding a new type of fruit. Ideally, I'd be able to do something like this:

```
class Food:
    @classmethod
    @fruitdecorator
    def apples(clss, amount):
        return '%d apple(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    @fruitdecorator
    def oranges(clss, amount):
        return '%d orange(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    def carrots(clss, amount):
        return '%d carrot(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    def all_fruit(clss, amount):
        pass # somehow return all methods decorated by @fruitdecorator

for method in Food.all_fruit():
    print method(Food, 2)
    # '2 apples'
    # '2 oranges'
```

I found [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910703/howto-get-all-methods-of-a-python-class-with-given-decorator) decorator [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707589/calling-functions-by-array-index-in-python/5707605#5707605) which let me do the following, which is OK, but I was wondering if it could be simplified at all. In this case I have to define this stuff and call it before, after, and use it in the fruit_baseket class method, which seems a little tedious. (I'm open to non-decorator solutions but they seem like the best way to keep the "mark" and the function definition close together.)

```
def MakeDecorator():
    registry = []
    def decorator(fn):
        # print dir(fn)
        registry.append(fn)
        return fn
    decorator.all = registry
    return decorator

fruitdecorator = MakeDecorator()

class Food:
    @classmethod
    @fruitdecorator
    def apples(clss, amount):
        return '%d apple(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    @fruitdecorator
    def oranges(clss, amount):
        return '%d orange(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    def carrots(clss, amount):
        return '%d carrot(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    def fruit_basket(clss, amount):
        basket = [xx(clss, amount) for xx in clss.fruit_methods]
        return basket


Food.fruit_methods = fruitdecorator.all
print Food.fruit_basket(2)
```

Comment: What Python version are you on? This is much easier in 3.6 with `__set_name__` (which, contrary to the name, isn't intended to be limited to setting names).

Comment: Good question: I'm using 2.7.10 and looking for the best solution with that. That being said, I'm open to tempting reasons to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A decorator takes a function and returns a function. I think your solution is maybe too general, unless you see a need for `vegetabledecorator` and `saladdecorator` markers, also.

```
Fruit_methods = []

def fruit(f):
    Fruit_methods.append(f)
    return f
```

Or, more generically:

```
import collections
Food_methods = collections.defaultdict(list)

def food_type(type):
    def store(f):
        Food_methods[type].append(f)
        return f
    return store
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this in a more clean, if somewhat more complicated way, using metaclasses. If you have your decorator flag its function in someway (for example, by adding a special attribute), then the metaclass can create a list as a class variable and populate it with the decorated functions (it can tell which have been decorated by looking for the special attribute). A sample implementation would be

```
class FoodMeta(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, dct):
        fruit_methods = []
        for key, value in dct.items():
            if hasattr(value, 'fruity'):
                fruit_methods.append(value)
        dct['fruit_methods'] = fruit_methods
        return super(FoodMeta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dct)

def fruitdecorator(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        # do whatever
        pass
    inner.fruity = True
    return inner

class Food(object):
    __metaclass__ = FoodMeta

    @fruitdecorator
    @classmethod
    def apples(clss, amount):
        return '%d apple(s)' % amount

    @fruitdecorator
    @classmethod
    def oranges(clss, amount):
        return '%d orange(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    def carrots(clss, amount):
        return '%d carrot(s)' % amount

    @classmethod
    def fruit_basket(clss, amount):
        basket = [xx(clss, amount) for xx in clss.fruit_methods]
        return basket

Food.fruit_methods # [Food.apples, Food.oranges]
```

A crucial thing to note in this solution is that the order of decorators matters: `fruitdecorator` must go on the outside (i.e., apply after) `classmethod`. This is because the `classmethod` decorator doesn't preserve the `fruity` attribute on the method, so the metaclass wouldn't know it was registered in the first place.