# Call a function by array index in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of functions and I want to call them by their index. However 
the following code gives me an error(*TypeError: 'list' object is not callable*)

```
kFunc = [Row(a,value, row), Col(a,value,col), Gridval(a,value, row, col), Grid(a, value), Rectangle(a, value, row, col)  ]
    k = random.randint(1,4)
    for j in range(k):
        output = kFunc[j]()
```

Each function returns a value. I tried replacing `kFunc[j]()` with `kFunc[j]`. I didn't get any error but all the 5 functions are getting executed.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707589/calling-functions-by-array-index-in-python) but I can't figure out an answer to my question.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably made a list of the return values already, assuming that `Row`, `Col`, etc. are the functions you are talking about. You can do the following to wrap those in functions:

```
kFunc = [
    lambda: Row(a,value, row), 
    lambda: Col(a,value,col), 
    lambda: Gridval(a,value, row, col), 
    lambda: Grid(a, value), 
    lambda: Rectangle(a, value, row, col)
]

output = kFunc[random.randint(0,4)]()  # will only do one of the lambda-wrapped operations
```